# docusign request "the authorization code" failed

Tags: authorization

I created an application with a developer account, Request the authorization code, the webpage reports an error, and no callback is made to the local address.

request url:

https://account-d.docusign.com/oauth/auth?response_type=code&scope=signature&client_id=c4039666-234a-41c9-8593-4d7297573059&redirect_uri=http://127.0.0.1:8000/loan-operation/v1/docusign/callback

return error:The custom error module does not recognize this error.